# Can't call method "getData" on an undefined value

Tags: xml, perl

im pasting some of buggy code:

```
eval
{
    if ( !( $doc = $parser->parse_file( $dir . $file ) ) )
    {
        print "Parse ERROR: " . $! . "\n";
        move( $dir . $file, $dirfailed . $file );
        next;
     }         
};

@nodes = $doc->findnodes("//story")or die "Can't find any '//story' nodes!";
foreach my $p_node  (@nodes)
{
  $titel = $p_node->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->getFirstChild->getData;
  print "TITEL:".$titel."\n" ;
  ## Content / News text
  $text ="";
  eval
  {
    $text = &formatText($p_node->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->getFirstChild->getData );
  };
  print "\nE R R O R: ".$@."\n" if $@;
```

here i'm getting the following error: E R R O R: Can't call method "getData" on an undefined value at /qflife/news/newsaktuell/news_aktuell_api.pl 
the body is there (in the file). 
but the error appears not always. i mean sometimes when i let the script run with the same file it can find the body. i duno what am i doing wrong.
any help'd be very appreciated!

thanks
greetings
magda muskala

Answer (score 4):

Please post the example XML which generates the error, and the line # that generates the error (e.g. is it the "title" or the "body" lookup?).

Most likely, this means that `getFirstChild` returned undef, which means the first node in the list had no children nodes (e.g. was an empty "title" tag).

Also, if you're getting your XML from a web connection as opposed to reading a file from filesystem, you may be getting corrupted/empty XML due to network issues.

To prevent the error, do something like:

```
my $body = $p_node->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->getFirstChild;
if (ref $body) { # Make sure it's an object
    $text = $body->getData;
} else {
    # Error handling
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably worth tracking down at which point your complex expression is actually failing. When you chain a number of method calls together like that, you'd better be pretty sure that they are all going to return something useful.

```
my $body = $p_node->getElementsByTagName("body");

unless ($body) {
  die "No body\n";
}

my $item = $body->item(0);

unless ($item) {
  die "No item\n";
}

my $first_child = $item->getFirstChild;

unless ($first_child) {
  die "No first child\n";
}

my $text = $first_child->getData;

unless ($text) {
  die "No text\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should verify the existence of each node along the path `$p_node->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->getFirstChild->getData`

Answer (score 0):

You are using XPath to get the stories, why don't you use it also to find the title, instead to using navigation? This way you either get a result or you don't, but at least you don't die trying!

I *think* that `$titel= $p_node->findvalue( '//title[1]/*[1]')` should be equivalent to what you wrote, although I suspect a simpler expression might also work (as others have mentioned, it's hard to test without an example of the XML you are processing).

I am assuming you are using XML::LibXML here BTW.